# Flutter Firebase unable to understand stack trace

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am unable to understand this stack trace and why it arising. From what I can understand it is something to do with firebase messaging.

```
E/AndroidRuntime(26033): java.lang.AssertionError
E/AndroidRuntime(26033):    at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.messaging.FlutterFirebasePermissionManager.onRequestPermissionsResult(FlutterFirebasePermissionManager.java:33)
E/AndroidRuntime(26033):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngineConnectionRegistry$FlutterEngineActivityPluginBinding.onRequestPermissionsResult(FlutterEngineConnectionRegistry.java:777)
E/AndroidRuntime(26033):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngineConnectionRegistry.onRequestPermissionsResult(FlutterEngineConnectionRegistry.java:409)
E/AndroidRuntime(26033):    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.onRequestPermissionsResult(FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.java:752)
E/AndroidRuntime(26033):    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult(FlutterActivity.java:748)
E/AndroidRuntime(26033):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchRequestPermissionsResult(Activity.java:8421)
E/AndroidRuntime(26033):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:8266)
E/AndroidRuntime(26033):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4931)
E/AndroidRuntime(26033):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4979)
E/AndroidRuntime(26033):    at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:51)
E/AndroidRuntime(26033):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
E/AndroidRuntime(26033):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
E/AndroidRuntime(26033):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2044)
E/AndroidRuntime(26033):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
E/AndroidRuntime(26033):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
E/AndroidRuntime(26033):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7562)
E/AndroidRuntime(26033):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(26033):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
E/AndroidRuntime(26033):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
I/Process (26033): Sending signal. PID: 26033 SIG: 9
Lost connection to device.
```

But as per documentation, my pre configuration for handling permission for both firebase and notification are correct.

This is what my main looks like,

```dart
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );

  FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

  NotificationSettings settings = await messaging.requestPermission(
    alert: true,
    announcement: false,
    badge: true,
    carPlay: false,
    criticalAlert: false,
    provisional: false,
    sound: true,
  );

  print('User granted permission: ${settings.authorizationStatus}');


  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

  await FirebaseMessaging.instance.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
      alert: true, badge: true, sound: true);

  DatabaseBinding().dependencies();

  runApp(MyApp());
}

Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
}
```

And below I am handling permissions in during my policy screen,

```dart
Map<Permission, PermissionStatus> statuses = await [
      Permission.storage,
      Permission.notification,
      Permission.camera
    ].request();

    if (!statuses.containsValue(PermissionStatus.denied)) {
      showGeneralDialog(
          context: context,
          useRootNavigator: false,......so_on
```

Please let me know, what exactly the stack trace says and if I am missing something please do explain.

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems like coming from update 13.0.0 - Inbuilt notification permission handling function

[FlutterFire issue#9430](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/9430)

Please follow above link for further details